# Ghostscript error

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript

I was told that Ghostscript is the best tool to downsize PDF files. I have GNU Ghostscript 7.07 installed. I use it through PHP with the following code :

```
system("gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 
   -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dPDFDEBUG -sOutputFile=output.pdf document.pdf");
```

For some files it works perfectly but for some other, the output file is either invalid or has a white page with nothing else. Could it be because of the version?

I got one error message:

```
Error:
  /syntaxerror in readxref Operand stack: Execution stack: %interp_exit 
  .runexec2  --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push 
  --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1 3 
  %oparray_pop 1 3 %oparray_pop 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 
  --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval--
Dictionary stack: 
  --dict:1064/1123(ro)(G)-- --dict:0/20(G)-- --dict:93/200(L)-- --dict:93/200(L)-- 
  --dict:97/127(ro)(G)-- --dict:229/230(ro)(G)-- --dict:14/15(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
```

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Ghostscript is exceedingy old, you should certainly start by upgrading, the current shipping version is 9.04.